# Slider control: marker restrictions?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, sliders

In slider controls, is there any restrictions about slider's marker? Is it context-dependent?

For instance, do you feel like this slider (taken from a desktop application built with Flex) could be a seek control in a multimedia player?

[image]

Somehow I get the feeling that triangle markers should be used to control settings and rounded markers for media seeking, but I don't know if this is a reasoned question. Is there any studies related?

Comment: Let us know if this is going to be a desktop application, website or touch app, and if so, what device it is for.

Comment: You are right, there was some info missing. I already update the question, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

A bunch of suggestions:

- size of the target matters, so make sure the draggable control is not too small for convenient use
- triangular shape makes the target half the size as it would be in case of being a rectangle. Of course you can make the rectangular area around the triangular control active, but anyway, users may be convinced that they need to click this triangle. As a result, they may find it inconvenient to use. To avoid it, try to use rectangular control pointing at the top:

[image]

- plus, you can make even bigger area around the control active.

Additionally, consider providing more control actions:

- users could use scroll wheel while pointing at the slider to operate it.
- the whole area of the slider could be active allowing direct access to some position on it

Comment: So do you think the shape of the target is not related to its functionality? For instance, is it ok if a multimedia time slider has the same target as an option slider to choose numbers?

Comment: I only suggest 'pumping it up' a little bit to make it better use the space and look and feel of being easier to drag while still pointing at the top.

Comment: Also, to make the slider even more precise, the markers could be moved above or under the line, so that only the tip is touching the bar.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about [**Fitts' law**](http://www.interaction-design.org/encyclopedia/fitts_law.html).

Since the seek bar will not be in any corner of the screen, the next easiest way to make it easily accessible is to **make it larger**. A circle of the same height as the triangle will have a larger target area for the user to select. Also, if you feel the slider container/bar is too small, you can make the circle larger than the height of the slider container.